# Included JSP page submit not triggering action button

Tags: jsp, jsf, include

I am trying to include another JSP page that has button actions. The include works fine but when I click on the button the page refreshes but it does not trigger my action listener. If I hit the button a second time it will then trigger the action button's listener. It seems like this is caused because of the fact that the action button is within the included page, but I don't know of a way around this other than just not doing a jsp include. I want to include this page on other pages and want to reuse the code.

The code is pretty simple. Just a standard . And the MyIncludedPage.jspf has a root  tag and then just standard components within it and a backing bean for the server side processing.

I am using JSF 1.2 and JSP 1.1

Answer (score 0):

Is this an issue of your caching configuration?

Also consider whether the route taken in the first case is different than the second (e.g. perhaps you're looking direct at the template in the first case, but visiting through a some extra logic and a forwarding redirect in the second case, which associates your bean properly.